# Tortoise Bazaar commit password

Tags: windows, ftp, tortoisebzr

I've recently set up a Bazaar repo on my FTP server (only access I have to back end, please don't go into reasons why I shouldn't use FTP).

I have managed to get everything working with short cuts such that I can include user and pass in the ftp URL:

```
ftp://"user":pass@host/path
```

Though I am trying to set up script that I can commit from a local directory with a batch file. The issue is I still require to put in the password everytime.

```
bzr commit "E:\Ryan - Backup\Other\test" -m batched
```

I had a crack at using the authentication.conf file but it either didn't work for me in this situation or I was doing it wrong. I placed the file in the .bzr folder so it was located at:

```
E:\Ryan - Backup\Other\Test\.bzr\authentication.conf
```

With the contents being:

```
# Identity on foo.net
[site]
scheme=ftp
host=site
user=username
password=pass
```

Am I doing something wrong or would I have to create a plugin to do what I am after.

P.S End result was to run a batch at startup and shut down so I could sync file updates between my computers.

**UPDATE:** I also tried the 
[guide](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.0/en/user-reference/#configuration-settings) that describes the location of:

```
C:\Users\rfleming\AppData\Roaming\bazaar\2.0
```

for the authetication.conf file, this didn't work either

**UPDATE 2:** Placing the authentication.conf into the:

```
C:\Users\rfleming\AppData\Roaming\bazaar\2.0
```

Worked fine and I just ended up using checkout and push for syncing and no manually password typing was required!